# How to capture value from textarea during form submission

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces

I am using textarea to capture book description but textarea doesn't have attribute "value", How to pass the value to bean.

But the following mechanism to capture value doesn't seem to work

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="3" spellcheck="false">#{_book.description}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try  `h:inputTextarea`

```
 <h:inputTextarea value="#{bean.text}" cols="35"/>
```

[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/inputTextarea.html)

EDIT:

```
 <div spellcheck="false">
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{user.test}" cols="80" rows="25"/>
    </div>
```

This seems to disable spell check for the given text area even though you enable it in firefox . I have tested in firefox only though.

Comment: yes, I tried with h:inputTextarea its working but it doesn't take the attribute spellcheck="false".

Comment: shouldn't you leave spell checking to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

If the `h:inputTextArea` is really no option for some reason, then just give it a name and grab it as request parameter the usual way as you would do when not using JSF at all.

E.g.

```
<textarea name="foo">#{bean.foo}</textarea>
```

with

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.foo}")
private String foo;
```

or if you aren't on JSF 2.0 yet:

```
<managed-property>
     <property-name>foo</property>
     <value>#{param.foo}</value>
</managed-property>
```

or if you'd like to do it manually:

```
public Bean() {
    this.foo = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .getRequestParameterMap().get("foo");
}
```